# poetry: create package to install in other directory

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I have own pip package. I made the package with poetry.

This package named **my_pack**. If I install this package, then it will install to location:

```
..\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\my_pack
```

But, I need for files of **my_pack** will install to directory of other package:

```
..\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\other_pack\internal_directory\
```

How change target location for package? Maybe, I need to edit pyproject.toml of my_pack?

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing it in your machine with `pip`, you probably need to change the default  path in pip (usually you'll find it in `~/.pip/pip.conf` or `~/.pip/pip.ini`

add (or edit) :

```
[global]
target = 'yourPath'
```

you can check the [pip doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) for more info.

Comment: No, this is not my way. I need tune my_pack for this package intalled in other PC.